# How do I type script characters in plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex

LaTeX has the canonical `\mathcal` for typing script characters in math mode.

Does Plain TeX have a similar ability?

Comment: `\def\mathcal#1{{\cal#1}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain TeX knows about a few math alphabets, which are called with the standard

```
\it \bf \sl \tt
```

commands. There are also `\mit` and the one that interests you, that is,

```
\cal
```

Beware that braces are needed around the symbols:

```
${\cal P}(X)$
```

might denote the power set of *X*. The same for the other commands in math mode: `\bf{x}` would be a big mistake, whereas `{\bf x}` is correct.

Note that `\cal` does something sensible only with uppercase letters.